# Mysql Dropping Connection

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, connection

I am on Instant Ruby on Rails Mysql version 5.0.27, developing a system and all was going ok (sort of). Now the database keeps dropping. I found some comments that the userid needs to be root and password blank, I had changed the password, so I changed it back.
Views run fine displaying and making changes than 500 Internal error, log says the Mysql connection dropped. Any clues??

Comment: I think I have the problem. NEVER STORE OBJECTS IN THE session. I beleive this retriction is coming from Apache or Mongrel which are processing the passing of messages back and forth between the app and other servers like Mysql. Mysql is being accessed by ROR via Active Record which wraos the Object around Mysqls format which are rows in a table. What I am wondering about is the sessions were being stored pn Mysql using Sessions. Is Sessions not using active record, or is my hunch about Aoache or Mongrel correct?

Comment: By the by remvoving the object from session seems to have solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (Mysql::Error: Lost connection to MySQL server during query: SELECT * FROM `events`   WHERE (`events`.`id` = 1) ):
followed by alot of falldown errors